# Using illegal names in MySQL through SQLObject

Tags: sql, mysql, reserved-words, sqlobject

How to use illegal names for MySQL with SQLObject?

In pure SQL it is possible to use backquotes, say:

```
    SELECT `select from` FROM table1 WHERE 1;
```

...can be used to select the field called `select from`. Is it possible to tell SQLObject to utilize backquotes?

Comment: It depends on your definition of 'pure SQL'; the backticks in MySQL are as non-standard as the square brackets in MS SQL Server.  The SQL standard requires such identifiers to be delimited - written inside double quotes.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: OK, double quotes might be fine as well. I'm looking for a way to access an existent DB with illegal names through SQLObject or another ORM.

Comment: If you turn on ANSI or ANSI_QUOTES in SQL_MODE you'll be able to use " in MySQL too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id INT(11),
  `select from` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1, 'test value');
```

to access `select from` from SQLObject, declare the column with backticks:

```
>>> class Table1(SQLObject):
...     myIllegallyNamedColumn = Col(dbName="`select from`")
... 
>>> list(Table1.select())
[<Table1 0 myIllegallyNamedColumn='test value'>]
```

Comment: I'd be wary about relying on this: apart from being MySQL-only, it seems like a bug that SQLObject is not properly escaping schema names already. Really this should be fixed in the library (at which point the above might break!)